# Python enchant suggests word that it can't check?

Tags: python, aspell, pyenchant

Is this not odd?

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb  1 2013, 20:24:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.check("house")
True
>>> d.check("civilization")
False
>>> d.suggest("civilization")
['civilization', 'civilizations', "civilization's"]
>>> d.provider
<Enchant: Aspell Provider>
>>> d.tag
'en_US'
>>> enchant.list_languages()
['de', 'de_AT', 'de_CH', 'de_DE', 'en', 'en_CA', 'en_GB', 'en_US']
```

So basically, spell-checking the word "civilization" fails, but when asked to suggest alternatives, enchant (or aspell?) suggests the very same word that it just failed to spell.

**EDIT:** Using this workaround

```
def spell(w) : return d.check(w) or w in d.suggest(w)
```

I can get more sensible answers from pyEnchant, but that seems like a hack to me.  However, this doesn't seem to be a pyEnchant problem but rather something to do with `aspell` itself:

```
echo "civilization" | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6.1)
& civilization 3 0: civilization, civilizations, civilization's
```

Or am I misreading the output here?

**EDIT:** After this question was closed, I've rephrased it more clearly in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867280/why-does-aspell-suggest-the-very-word-that-it-fails-to-check) thread.

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing with the `en_GB` dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely odd :)

Comment: Without knowing the enchant library, it definitely seems odd to me.  Maybe file a bug report?

Comment: @mbatchkarov: Same thing :)

Comment: More to the point, I voted to close this as "Not a real question" because you don't really have a concrete question here.  This is more of a comment that the package isn't working how you expect it to, and there's not much we can do to help that other than give you a little moral support ... I do hope that you contact the developers of this package and figure out how to get this issue resolved though.

Comment: @mgilson Agreed, +1 for being interesting though

Comment: @mgilson: It seems that pyEnchant hasn't been maintained for about two years.  As for this not being a question: perhaps I ought to ask, "Is this expected behavior?"