# Why does aspell suggest the very word that it fails to check?

Tags: aspell, hunspell

Here is the command I run:

```
> echo "civilization" | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6.1)
& civilization 3 0: civilization, civilizations, civilization's
```

Why does aspell suggest the very word ("civilization") but fails to check its spelling?  In contrast, hunspell seems to get this right

```
> echo "civilization" | hunspell
Hunspell 1.3.2
*
```

but that is probably because the two spell checkers use different dictionaries.

**EDIT:** Running this on a different machine and different/older aspell version seems to work though:

```
> echo civilization | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.3)
*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Kevin Atkinson (aspell maintainer, [link](http://aspell.net/)) that's a *bug* and he wasn't sure if there's a report open for it.  He wasn't sure if/when this will get fixed either.

Comment: should be fixed here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=827033

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase and lowercase
What you get, if you try it with `Civilization` ?

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

T:\msys\1.0\src\aspell-0.60.6\.libs>echo "zivilisation" | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6)
& zivilisation 3 1: Zivilisation, Zivilisationen, Sterilisation

T:\msys\1.0\src\aspell-0.60.6\.libs>echo "Zivilisation" | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6)
*

T:\msys\1.0\src\aspell-0.60.6\.libs>
```

Comment: That's an `echo "Zivilisation"` with a "Z" not a "C".

Comment: That's an `de` not `en` dictonary . Only to show what you get with first letter `Z` and `z`.